# Does this recursive call eventually crash the web page?

Tags: javascript, html, performance, function, recursion

I was working on a typewriter effect for a web page with the use of java script.

```js
const wordList = ["word 1","word 2","word 3"];
let word = wordList[0];
let temp = "";
let complete = false;
let i = 0;
let blinkTime = 650;
let type = ()=>{
    async function myDisplay(){
        let myPromise = new Promise(function (res,rej){
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(!complete){
                    temp = word.slice(0,temp.length + 1);
                }
                else{
                    temp = word.slice(0,temp.length - 1);
                }
                res(temp);
            },Math.floor(Math.random()*300 + 100));
        });
        document.getElementById("type").innerHTML = await myPromise;
    }
    myDisplay().then(function (){
        if(temp===word && !complete){
            complete = true;
            setTimeout(function(){type();},3000);
        }
        else if (temp === "" && complete){
            complete = false;
            i = (i+1)%wordList.length;
            word = wordList[i]
            type();
        }
        else{
            type();
        }
    });
}
let blink = function(){
    let myPromise = new Promise(function(res){
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("type").style.borderRightStyle = "solid";   
        },blinkTime);
        res();
    });   
    myPromise.then(function(){
        setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById("type").style.borderRightStyle = "none";
            blink();    
        },2*blinkTime);
    });
}
type();
blink();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]>      <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="">
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--[if lt IE 7]>
            <p class="browsehappy">You are using an <strong>outdated</strong> browser. Please <a href="#">upgrade your browser</a> to improve your experience.</p>
        <![endif]-->
        <span id="type"></div>
        <span id="type2"> hello there</div>
        <script src="./script/myScript.js" async defer></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

The program runs perfectly fine, but I am a novice in java script and to my knowledge recursive calls that don't have a proper **end** is not a good programming practice. In the above java script code the `type()` function and the `blink()` function never end their recursive calls, is this a concerning issue that might break the webpage, or am I missing some concept here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not an issue:

There is in fact no (pure) recursion going on. It is not a `type` execution context that makes the call to `type` (same holds for `blink`). The seemingly "recursive" call is made from within an other function context: either the one given to `setTimeout` or the one given to a promise's `then` method. Such callbacks are executed *asynchronously*, meaning that they are executed from a state where the call stack is guaranteed to be *empty*.

There is never a situation where an execution context of `type` is pending for the return of a "recursive" call of `type`, and so there is no situation where the call stack can grow out of capacity.